# How to find the paired value of earliest date?

Tags: excel, vba, date

Imagine the following table in excel:

| Name | Created Date |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021.01.01. |
| Mike | 2010.01.02. |
| Luke | 2010.01.03. |

I would like to get John as returned value.
The following code works fine, but it returns the earliest date:

```
Dim earliest as date, latest as Date
earliest = worksheetfunction.Min(Range("A1:A100"))
latest = worksheetfunction.Max(Range("A1:A100")
debug.print earliest
```

I would like to get the paired value of the earliest date, which is in one column left to the created date.

Comment: The "paired value" meaning you want to find a matching date?  What have you attempted to modify in the existing code?

Comment: I would like to get the name of earliest date

Comment: So you want to A) `application.min(columns(2))`, B) `application.match(A,columns(2),0)`, then C) `debug.print index(columns(1),B)`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this task, this is only one version:

```
Sub test()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim MinDate As Date
    Dim MinRng As Long
    Dim myName As String
    
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("B2:B" & lr)
        
    MinDate = CDate(WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng))
    MinRng = Rng.Find(What:=MinDate, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        
    myName = Cells(MinRng, 1)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice this will return only first coincidence, so if there is more than 1 paired value for same earliest date, it will return just first one.

```
Sub test()
Dim MyWF As WorksheetFunction
Dim MyResult As String

Set MyWF = WorksheetFunction

'Let's say column B hold dates and column A the names
MyResult = MyWF.Index(Range("A1:A100"), MyWF.Match(MyWF.Min(Range("B1:B100")), Range("B1:B100"), 0))

Debug.Print MyResult

Set MyWF = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, notice that `Range("A1:A100")` and `Range("B1:B100")` must be same size for this to work properly.